# How to use object as an constructor?

Tags: javascript

i am new to javascript, and a little bit confused on how to set object as an constructor, so lets say i have some object :

```js
var avenger1 ={
    firstName : "Tony",
    lastName : "Stark",
    from : "New York",
    parents : {
        father : "Howard Stark",
        mother : "maria Stark"
    },
    getSummary : function(){
        return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName} is a wealthy businessman from ${this.from}, born to  ${this.parents.father} dan ${this.parents.mother}`
    }
}

console.log(avenger1.getSummary())
```

and i am trying to build that object as  constructor, here my code :

```js
function Avenger(firstName, lastName,from, parents.father, parents.mother){
    this.firstName = firstName,
    this.lastName =  lastName,
    this.from = from,
    this.parents.father = parents.father,
    this.parents.mother = parents.mother,
    getSummary : function(){
        return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName} is a wealthy businessman from ${this.from}, born to  ${this.parents.father} dan ${this.parents.mother}`
    }
}

var  Avenger1 = new Avenger("Tony", "Stark","New York", "Howard","Maria ");
```

how do i set those parents like firstName etc, so that it does not error ? 
I am sorry if my questions is a little bit to easy..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few mistakes on your code:

**1)** Do not use `dot` (`.`) on the argument names.

**2)** Use `semicolons` (`;`) to end your sentences (just a recommendation)

**3)** Do not use `:` to assign a value to a variable inside the `Avenger` constructor (in reference to this: `getSummary : function(){...}`). `Avenger` is not an object now...

In summary, your code can be reworked to this one:

```js
function Avenger(firstName, lastName, from, father, mother)
{
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName =  lastName;
    this.from = from;
    this.parents = {father, mother};
    this.getSummary = function()
    {
        return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName} is a wealthy businessman from ${this.from}, born to  ${this.parents.father} dan ${this.parents.mother}`
    };
}

var  Avenger1 = new Avenger("Tony", "Stark","New York", "Howard","Maria ");
console.log(Avenger1.getSummary());
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: Omg thank you, so i added  some array in my constructor, and use your suggestion and it works !! I can not thank you enough for this :)

Comment: @Binarian_Girl You can vote-up the answers that were useful to you, and accept one of the answer, the most useful to you. That is a good way of say thanks to all of us... :-)

Answer (score 2):

Doing great! Just have a syntax error where commas could be deleted or replaced by semicolon, method should be attached with this, and arguments father and mother can be accessed directly.

```
function Avenger(firstName, lastName, from, father, mother){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName =  lastName;
    this.from = from;
    this.parents = {
      father: father,
      mother: mother
    };
    this.getSummary = function(){
        return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName} is a wealthy businessman from ${this.from}, born to  ${this.parents.father} dan ${this.parents.mother}`
    }
}

var  Avenger1 = new Avenger("Tony", "Stark","New York", "Howard","Maria ");
```

MDN is a great resource too if need to hear it in different words, helps me sometimes to hear people talk about it in two different ways.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

Answer (score 1):

```js
function Avenger(firstName, lastName, from, father, mother) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.from = from;
  this.parents = {
    father: father,
    mother: mother
  };
  this.getSummary = function() {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName} is a wealthy businessman from ${this.from}, born to ${this.parents.father} and ${this.parents.mother}.`;
  };
}

var avenger1 = new Avenger("Tony", "Stark", "New York", "Howard", "Maria");
console.log(avenger1.getSummary());
```